# unable to get global variable value of one python file in another python file

Tags: python, pycharm, global-variables

file 2.py

```
name1 = []
class VideoCamera(object):

   def process_and_encode(images):
   # initialize the list of known encodings and known names
   known_encodings = []
   known_names = []
   name1 = []
   print("[LOG] Encoding faces ...")

    for image_path in tqdm(images):
        #  For Loading  image
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        # Converting it from BGR to RGB
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # detect face in the image and get its location (square boxes coordinates)
        boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model='hog')

        # Encode the face into a 128-d embeddings vector
        encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, boxes)

        # the person's name is the name of the folder where the image comes from
        name = image_path.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

        if len(encoding) > 0:
            known_encodings.append(encoding[0])
            known_names.append(name)
            name1.append(name)
            print (name1)

    return {"encodings": known_encodings, "names": known_names,"name1": name1}
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request,session,Response
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from camera import *
from twilio.rest import Client
import time
import random
@app.route('/otp',methods=['POST'])
def otp():
     print("Name")
     print(name1)
if name1 == "Tejaswi":
    return render_template('sucess.html')
else:
    return render_template('failed.html')
```

In main.py []-empty list is printing it is not printing the updated value of name1. How to print the gloabla variable value in this main.py..
Now i have edited like this but still output is empty list only

Please help me!!

Comment: Did you import the value?

Comment: That can't be all the code for `main.py`.  Please show us all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've edited a couple of things. Here is file2.py...

```
class VideoCamera(object):
   global name1
   def process_and_encode(images):
   # initialize the list of known encodings and known names
        known_encodings = []
        known_names = []
        name1 = []
        print("[LOG] Encoding faces ...")

        for image_path in tqdm(images):
            #  For Loading  image
            image = cv2.imread(image_path)
            # Converting it from BGR to RGB
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            # detect face in the image and get its location (square boxes coordinates)
            boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(image, model='hog')

            # Encode the face into a 128-d embeddings vector
            encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, boxes)

            # the person's name is the name of the folder where the image comes from
            name = image_path.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

            if len(encoding) > 0:
                known_encodings.append(encoding[0])
                known_names.append(name)
                name1.append(name)
                print (name1)

                return {"encodings": known_encodings, "names": known_names,"name1": name1}
```

And here is main.py

```
from file2 import VideoCamera

@app.route('/otp',methods=['POST'])
def otp():
     print("Name")
     print(name1)
     if process_and_encode().name1 == "Tejaswi":
        return render_template('sucess.html')
     else:
        return render_template('failed.html')
```

Comment: main.py never defines `name1`, so I don't see how it can run.

Comment: It instantiates the variable name1 as an empty list. The values should be appended when  you add them to the list. The thing is I can't do more from here because I get an error on line 3 on main.py, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Ya facing the same issue

Comment: That's because you need a link to the OTP file. I don't have it, but you should since it's your code.

Comment: after linking its displaying failed.html only as its getting empty list